# Plugin to Outlook to draw attention to names removed added in a thread

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

Does a feature exist in Outlook (2010 specifically), and if not is there a plugin out there that does the following:

In an email that is a reply, I would like the interface to show who might have been added to or removed from the thread. I envision it as displaying removed names with a strikeout, and added names in an alternate color.

In business emails where many people can be on the To: and CC: lines, I find it pretty annoying to figure out which single person was removed from a thread mid-way through it.

Comment: I'm starting to think this doesn't exist :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Sounds like a great feature, though, and I can definitely see where this would be helpful. [Send Microsoft a suggestion!](http://www.microsoft.com/office/community/en-us/wizard.mspx?type=suggestion)